# apache Access Control Allow Origin issue

Tags: apache, cors

We have added following settings to enable CORS for both domains a.domain.com and b.domain.com

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

But still getting error.

> Font from origin 'http://b.domain.com' has been blocked from loading by Cross-Origin Resource Sharing policy: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://a.domain.com' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

I know this is simple setting, and we are successfully using it, but in this case no luck.

http://enable-cors.org/server_apache.html

[How does Access-Control-Allow-Origin header work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)

Comment: Try restarting the Apache webserver. And where did you placed SET HEADER code ?

Answer (score 0):

For us this worked only from the same domain. We are trying to add the Origin in the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the BE depending if is allowed in a list of allowed origin addresses.
But we have issues with Apache right now, because it adds this header with value `*` all the time.

That is because of Apache config line:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

We try to see if we can execute this only on some of the requests.

Answer (score -1):

Add `.htaccess` file to your Application's root folder, and place the following code in it

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

Comment: We have disabled allowoverride

Comment: oh okay, Then the header module is httpd.conf file is enabled?